# Wet Basement, slab lower than the footer

Tags: basement, drain, wet

The slab in my basement is lower than the houses footer. I have tried installing a foundation drain on the exterior with the pipe level with the footer but this did not fix the problem due to the basement slab being lower than the footer. My fear is that cutting a perimeter drain in the basement may weaken the foundations footing. Are there any other suggestions I might try? The basement slab sits at the bottom of the footing.

Comment: Is your slab modern, do you have vb, drainage layer and insulation?

Answer (score 2):

Put in a sump pit and see what it does for you.

If you knew the slab was lower than the footer you could have placed your external drain both away from (outside of) and below the footer, so as to not undermine the footer by being below it but right next to it where the load is being transferred to the soil below. Presumably installing that was a lot of hassle and expense you won't want to do over.

[image: Image from concretenetwork.com showing transfer of load from a footing into soil]

A drain pipe can be located below the footer by also being far enough away from the footer that it does not impact the bearing.

This would suggest that your sump pit's closest edge should be away from the (inside) edge of the footer by at least its depth, as well.